# How to properly attach plist files using skpsmtpmessage?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, email, background, smtp

Every time i try to attach plist files via the skpsmtpmessage library, they show up in the email with their proper respective names, but are 0 bytes in size. Here is the code :

```
-(void) sendMessage{

NSLog(@"Start Sending");

SKPSMTPMessage *test_smtp_message = [[SKPSMTPMessage alloc] init];
test_smtp_message.fromEmail = @"jaredloo@live.com.sg";
test_smtp_message.toEmail = @"vest@un0wn.org";
test_smtp_message.relayHost = @"smtp.live.com";
test_smtp_message.requiresAuth = YES;
test_smtp_message.login = @"jaredloo@live.com.sg";
test_smtp_message.pass = @"blabla";
test_smtp_message.wantsSecure = YES; // smtp.gmail.com doesn't work without TLS!
test_smtp_message.subject = @"An application has crashed!";




//    test_smtp_message.bccEmail = @"testbcc@test.com";

// Only do this for self-signed certs!
// test_smtp_message.validateSSLChain = NO;
test_smtp_message.delegate = self;

NSMutableArray *parts_to_send = [NSMutableArray array];

//If you are not sure how to format your message part, send an email to your self.  
//In Mail.app, View > Message> Raw Source to see the raw text that a standard email client will generate.
//This should give you an idea of the proper format and options you need
    /*NSDictionary *plain_text_part = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                     @"text/plain\r\n\tcharset=UTF-8;\r\n\tformat=flowed", kSKPSMTPPartContentTypeKey,
                                     [@"Sample message body here!" stringByAppendingString:@"\n"], kSKPSMTPPartMessageKey,
                                     @"quoted-printable", kSKPSMTPPartContentTransferEncodingKey,
                                     nil];
    [parts_to_send addObject:plain_text_part];*/



    //NSString *image_path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Success" ofType:@"png"];
    NSArray *crashList = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:@"/User/Library/Logs/CrashReporter" error:nil];
    NSLog(@"CrashList: %@", crashList);
    if ([crashList count] != 0)
    {
        for (int i=0; i < [crashList count]; i++) {
            NSString *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/User/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/%@",[crashList objectAtIndex:i]];
            NSData *crashData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath]; 
            NSString *directory = @"text/directory;\r\n\tx-unix-mode=0644;\r\n\tname=\"";
            directory = [directory stringByAppendingFormat: filePath];
            directory = [directory stringByAppendingFormat: @"\""];
            NSString *attachment = @"attachment;\r\n\tfilename=\"";
            attachment = [attachment stringByAppendingFormat: filePath];
            attachment = [attachment stringByAppendingFormat: @"\""];
            NSDictionary *image_part = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                        directory,kSKPSMTPPartContentTypeKey,
                                        attachment,kSKPSMTPPartContentDispositionKey,
                                        [crashData encodeBase64ForData],kSKPSMTPPartMessageKey,
                                        @"base64",kSKPSMTPPartContentTransferEncodingKey,nil];
            /*
             [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
             @"text/directory;\r\n\tx-unix-mode=0644;\r\n\tname=\"test.vcf\"",kSKPSMTPPartContentTypeKey,
             @"attachment;\r\n\tfilename=\"test.vcf\"",kSKPSMTPPartContentDispositionKey,
             [vcard_data encodeBase64ForData],kSKPSMTPPartMessageKey,
             @"base64",kSKPSMTPPartContentTransferEncodingKey,nil];

            */
            [parts_to_send addObject:image_part];
        }
    }

test_smtp_message.parts = parts_to_send;

[test_smtp_message send];

}
```

Here is the email (on the side of vest@un0wn.org) [GMAIL]

```
Jared Aaron Loo jaredloo@live.com.sg to me

show details 3:58 PM (39 minutes ago) 
6 attachments — Download all attachments  

    /User/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/LatestCrash-TableViewControl.plist
0K   Import to Contacts   Download  
    /User/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/LatestCrash-iSoda.plist
0K   Import to Contacts   Download  
    /User/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/LatestCrash.plist
0K   Import to Contacts   Download  
    /User/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/TableViewController_09_2011-10-18-104430_Jareds-iPhone.plist
0K   Import to Contacts   Download  
    /User/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/TableViewController_09_2011-10-18-104822_Jareds-iPhone.plist
0K   Import to Contacts   Download  
    /User/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/iSoda_2011-10-18-105543_Jareds-iPhone.plist
0K   Import to Contacts   Download
```

Any help is very much appreciated! :)

Comment: I've used similar code as shown here and no issues so far. What does your console/logs say? Maybe the images are too large?

Answer (score 0):

There are (at least) two probable causes for this:

```
 NSData *crashData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
```

and

```
 ...
 [crashData encodeBase64ForData],kSKPSMTPPartMessageKey, 
 ...
```

The first one may fail if you are unable to read the file from disk and the second may fail if your base64 encoding fails for some reason. Try inserting validations for nil results for either of these methods and handle the error properly.

Comment: I have ascertained that both crashData and kSKPSMTPPartMessageKey are not nil at the time of sending. I have even tried replacing encodeBase64ForData with encodeWrappedBase64ForData but to no avail.

Comment: Have you looked at the raw email being sent/received? Maybe that could give a clue.

Comment: Hi, I have implemented the exact same logic in another sample app, and that seems to work. However when it is implemented in my app, it does not. Have no clue why =/